# Puppet Server Can't restart

Tags: server, puppet, systemctl

I am trying to restart puppet server after using it for sometime and below is the error.

Any idea how to overcome this error?

> ```
> [root@chakriin56 user]# free -m
>               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
> Mem:           7820        2889        4080          86         851        4579
> Swap:          7812           0        7812
> [root@chakriin56 user]# puppet status
> {
>   "is_alive": true,
>   "version": "4.5.3"
> }
> [root@chakriin56 user]# systemctl status puppetserver.service
> Unit puppetserver.service could not be found.
> [root@chakriin56 user]# service puppetserver status
> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status puppetserver.service
> Unit puppetserver.service could not be found.
> [root@chakriin56 user]# systemctl restart puppetserver
> Failed to restart puppetserver.service: Unit not found.
> [root@chakriin56 user]#
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the available services via the command `puppet resource service`.  In that list, find the correct name for the Puppetserver service as it is installed on your machine, and use that to restart it.

If no such service is listed then your Puppetserver installation is damaged or non-standard.  Supposing the former to be more likely, in that case you could try reinstalling.  You might or might not be able to do that without first killing the running Puppetserver instance.  Be sure to back up your configuration, data, and manifest set before attempting a reinstallation.